# Setting properties of a C# object during vs.after creation

Tags: c#

Can someone help me understand the differences between creating an instance of an object and passing values during creation versus creating it then setting the properties?

When I set a trace on the object creation I can see `domainName`, `id`, and `guid` come into the class but it just bypasses setting the `guid` altogether. Is it because my SASReadToken value is 'null' that it stops?

This works:

```
TenantEntityModel tenantEntity = new TenantEntityModel
{
    PartitionKey = domainName,
    RowKey = id,
    SASReadToken = null,
    ApiKey = guid
};
TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.Insert(tenantEntity);
```

Passing the values during creation gives me all zeros for the `guid`:

```
TenantEntityModel tenantEntity = new TenantEntityModel(domainName, id, null, guid);
TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.Insert(tenantEntity);
```

Here is my class:

```
public class TenantEntityModel : TableEntity
{
    public string SASReadToken { get; set; }
    public Guid ApiKey { get; set; }

    public TenantEntityModel(string TenantDomainName, string Id, string SASReadToken, Guid ApiKey)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = TenantDomainName;
        this.RowKey = Id;
    }

    public TenantEntityModel() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor of `TenantEntityModel(string, string, string, Guid)` you are not setting `ApiKey` to any value. Try this:

```
public class TenantEntityModel : TableEntity
{
    public string SASReadToken { get; set; }
    public Guid ApiKey { get; set; }

    public TenantEntityModel(string TenantDomainName, string Id, string SASReadToken, Guid ApiKey)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = TenantDomainName;
        this.RowKey = Id;
        this.SASReadToken = SASReadToken;
        this.ApiKey = ApiKey;
    }

    public TenantEntityModel() { }
}
```

Note, this code: `new TenantEntityModel {...}` is not a *"passing paramters to constructor"*, but *"use default (parameterless constructor) and set properties one-by-one"*

*Remark:*

As for me, I usually not setting properties with publicly available setters through constructor, because you can always do this as in your code sample:

```
var tenantEntity = new TenantEntityModel
{
    PartitionKey = domainName,
    RowKey = id,
    SASReadToken = null,
    ApiKey = guid
};
```

So, if your `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` setters are publicly available (as I can see), your constructor `TenantEntityModel(string, string, string, Guid)` is mostly useless.

Comment: Woops! I forgot I had another constructor to handle the case where I have all three values. So my clarifying question is...should I create a constructor for scenarios where `SASReadToken` is null or is it possible to build a single constructor to handle these cases (i.e. `string SASReadToken`)?

Comment: I may have found an answer to this too. It seems if you pass parameters to an object for creation, it will initialize the object against the constructor with the right match for parameters passed to it. If you have a blank constructor it, and 'new it up', then set properties afterward, you can get away with one constructor instead of creating several to handle each case.

Comment: @JasonShave-MSFT check my edits, key thing: `new TenantEntityModel {...}` will not call `TenantEntityModel(string, string, string, Guid)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and tip. When you say 'publicly available setters' are you referring to my SASReadToken and ApiKey properties? Still learning the basics here but what would you set them to (private?)?

Comment: No, I mean setters, that are publicly available:) I will try to explain. In common, C# object properties are defining like this: `public string PropertyName { get { return someValue; } set { someValue = value; } }`. **Getter** is `get { ... }` part, and **Setter** is `set { ... }` part of this line. There is a short-hand variant to this: `public string SomePropertyName { get; set; }` - this setter and getter are public too. They maybe private/protected: `public string SomePropertyName { get; private set; }`, or readonly `public string SomePropertyName { get; }`

Comment: There is a nice [docs about properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). Have a look.

Answer (score 4):

When you do this:

```
TenantEntityModel tenantEntity = new TenantEntityModel
{
    PartitionKey = domainName,
    RowKey = id,
    ApiKey = guid
};
```

You are effectively doing this:

```
TenantEntityModel tenantEntity = new TenantEntityModel();
tenantEntity.PartitionKey = domainName;
tenantEntity.RowKey = id;
tenantEntity.ApiKey = guid;
```

This shouldn't be confused with passing parameters to your constructor (which you are doing in your second example). Your constructor doesn't do anything with the `SASReadToken` and `ApiKey` parameters. That is why they are being ignored.

If you want your constructor to do the work, you would need something like:

```
public TenantEntityModel(string TenantDomainName, string Id, string SASReadToken, Guid ApiKey)
{
    this.PartitionKey = TenantDomainName;
    this.RowKey = Id;
    this.SASReadToken = SASReadToken;
    this.ApiKey = ApiKey;
}
```

Comment: Can you see my comment on the other answer and respond? Thumbs up to both of you. My mistake on forgetting to set the properties. Found this gem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer

Comment: @Jason, vansily.sib made a valid observation in his remarks. If the constructor(s) are only setting publicly settable properties, then they may not really be required since you can just set these values in code. Up to you, though. There are numerous variations you could have to do this. It really depends on how the class will be used in your project.

Comment: @vasily.sib the answers were posted 32 seconds apart. It's programming, often the answer will be obvious to more than one person.

Comment: @NigelWhatling don't be snarky. It doesn't help.